# How to save class type as variable in c#?

Tags: c#, parametric-polymorphism

In c#, can you do something like this?

```
type typeOfInt = type(int);
int x = (typeOfInt)1;
```

Basically I want to store a type as a variable, so I can use the variable as a cast.
I am trying to do this because in me parametric polymorphism function, a variable could be 1 of 2 types. Both types has the same methods I want to use, but it wont let me use it because it's of a variable type.

```
    public static void SetFolderOrderValue<T>(T item, int value, Report reportObject)
    {
        if (!item.Exists)
        {
            reportObject.Log("The folder \"" + item.Name + "\" does not exist.");
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            item.SetProperty(folderOrderProperty, value);
            item.Update();
        }
        catch (SPException ex)
        {
            reportObject.Log("An error occurred when saving changes to the folder \"" + item.Name + "\". Maybe due to concurrent changes from another user. Please try again after a minute.\n" + Report.GetErrorInfo(ex));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            reportObject.Log("An error occured with \"" + item.Name + "\":\n" + Report.GetErrorInfo(ex));
        }
    }
```

If I can at least store the cast as a value, then I can just pass another boolean in the function saying which of the 2 types it is.

Comment: booleans to do polymorphism is a bad idea. Can you add the necessary to the declaration "where..." to get the base class, or is there no base class/interface

Comment: All object's in .net derive from Object, ence all object's have the method GetType() which return a Type Object.

Comment: @doctorlove, I am not sure what you mean. I know the class will either be SPFile or SPFolder. Both have the same methods that I use above. But I dont know how to access them the way there are used currently.

Comment: C# generics are compile-time constructs, but `GetType()` method and type checks are a run-time guys, so you can't leverage static typing here. You can use reflection or C# dynamics to call any method by name or check `item` type against all possible types using `as` operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are talking about polymorphism, so use it.

If you have 2 types with *same* or *common* methods and you have a function or set of functions to act on them, define an `interface` that describes that set of methods shared between those 2 types and :

If the types you're talking about are named `SPFile` and `SPFolder`

```
public class SPFile : IMyNewInterface  {
   .....
}

public class SPFolder : IMyNewInterface  {
   ...
}

public static void SetFolderOrderValue<T>(T item, int value, 
              Report reportObject) where T : IMyNewInterface    {
     ...
}
```

Comment: +1. However, I dont see the need for generics at all here... Just replace T with the new interface and remove <T>.

Comment: @justnS. I don't see evidence of necessity or absence of it in question, so just follow the pattern of OP, hoping that he knows what he does.

Comment: Fair point, just seems unnecessary to me when you know the interface you are expecting.

Comment: I am getting syntax errors when I put `public static void SetFolderOrderValue<T>(T item, int value, 
              Report reportObject) : where T IMyNewInterface    {...}`.

Comment: @omega: The correct syntax would be `public static void SetFolderOrderValue<T>(T item, int value, Report reportObject) where T : IMyNewInterface {...}`. Tigran misplaced the colon.

Comment: Note he will also have to make SPFile and SPFolder both implement the IMyNewInterface

Comment: @Tigran yes, but for someone that has never used an interface it's nice to show them they'll have to open the SPFile/SPFolder files and add the public class SPFile : IMyNewInterface in addition to changing the SetFolderOrderValue, and they might not even have access to change those classes.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this.

My answer assumes that [Tigran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551426/572644) doesn't apply, maybe because you can't change the types in question.

The following would be one way to achieve what you want to do:

```
var varOfTypeOne = item as TypeOne;
if(varOfTypeOne != null)
{
    varOfTypeOne.CallMethod();
    return;
}
var varOfTypeTwo = item as TypeTwo;
if(varOfTypeTwo != null)
{
    varOfTypeTwo.CallMethod();
    return;
}
```

Another way would be to use the DLR via `dynamic`:

```
dynamic dynamicItem = item;
dynamicItem.CallMethod();
```

This will fail at runtime if the actual type of `item` doesn't define `CallMethod`, so you are basically losing compile time safety.

BTW: A void method that takes a generic parameter without constraint usually can simply be replaced by a method that is non-generic and has `object` as the parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save the type but this is probably a code smell.

Read up on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx

Here is an example

```
int x = 1;
var type = x.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(type);
```

Comment: This doesn't help the OP achieve what he wants.

Comment: How does learning more about Type and GetType not help?  I noted that this is a code smell -- hoping to lead the answer toward polymorphism

Comment: Well, clearly by his example he was looking for class inheritance. But in the end he said he wanted to store the "type cast". Your example only stores a string.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't help OP, but it helps this guy who googled for this particular answer,